# No of pairs formed?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If given a set of positive integers greater than zero = [ A1 , A2, A3 , A4 , A5....An ]

We have to find the maximum number of pairs such that difference between 2nd and first element is greater than equal to 2. pair ( x , y ) : y >= 2 + x

You can't use same element in two subsets/pairs.

```
example: set  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
posible pairs [1, 3] , [2, 5]  
total pairs = 2
```

First I tried solving using permutations but it is wrong as can be seen.
I don't know if it is combinatorics or number theory problem.
Sure doesn't get solved with my limited knowledge of premutations.

Comment: I think that you might also have to make some assumptions about your set of numbers. Are they all integers?

Comment: They are all  positive integers greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $A_1\lt A_2\lt A_3\lt\cdots\lt A_n$. If $n$ is odd, then

$$\{(A_1,A_n),(A_2,A_{n-1}),(A_3,A_{n-2}),\ldots\}$$

will do the trick (the middle element, $A_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}$, will be unpaired).  If $n$ is divisible by $4$, then

$$\{(A_1,A_3),(A_2,A_4),(A_5,A_7),(A_6,A_8),\ldots\}$$

will do the trick. And if $n\gt2$ is even but not divisible by $4$, then

$$\{(A_1,A_n),(A_2,A_4),(A_3,A_5),(A_6,A_8),(A_7,A_9)\ldots\}$$

will do the trick. In all cases, aside from $n=2$, the number of pairs is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Finally, for the case $n=2$, there are *no* pairs if $A_2=A_1+1$ and *one* pair if $A_2\gt A_1+1$.